# Why can't I map my state+dispatch to this component? (TS error TS2741)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I've got a React component that should have 3 props:

- `isLoggedIn` from local state
- `logInUser` is an action dispatcher
- `user` from redux state

Why does the following component generate this typescript error?
Shouldn't `user` & `logInUser` be provided by `connect()`?

```
/Users/myuser/sites/my-site/src/components/App/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/my-user/sites/my-site/src/components/App/index.tsx(11,8): 
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<LoginProps>': user, logInUser  TS2739

     9 |   return (
    10 |     <div className="App">
  > 11 |       <Login />
       |        ^
```

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { user } from '../../redux/types';
import { RootStore } from '../../redux/store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logInUser } from '../../redux/actions';
import { LogInUserAction } from '../../redux/actionTypes';

type LoginProps = {
  user: user; // from redux state
  logInUser: () => LogInUserAction; // action dispatcher
};
type LoginLocalState = { isLoggedIn: boolean }; // local component state

export class Login extends Component<LoginProps, LoginLocalState> {

  constructor(props: LoginProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    } as LoginLocalState;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>This is where the login button will go</h2>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// state & actions for component
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootStore) => ({ user: state.user });
const mapActionsToProps = { logInUser };

// export default VisibilityFilters;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Login);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you importing `Login` ?

If you are importing it like this `import { Login } from '...'` this is the source of the error because you are importing the plain (not connected) component.

You can import 2 things from your login component file.

1. The plain component (you have to provide every props to it, including `dispatch` and so on...)
2. The connected component (as default) that wil automatically have the props such as `dispatch` filled.

Maybe you shouldnt export the plain component and change your import to `import Login from '...'` (default import).

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { user } from '../../redux/types';
import { RootStore } from '../../redux/store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logInUser } from '../../redux/actions';
import { LogInUserAction } from '../../redux/actionTypes';

type LoginProps = {
  user: user; // from redux state
  logInUser: () => LogInUserAction; // action dispatcher
};
type LoginLocalState = { isLoggedIn: boolean }; // local component state

class Login extends Component<LoginProps, LoginLocalState> {

  constructor(props: LoginProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    } as LoginLocalState;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>This is where the login button will go</h2>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// state & actions for component
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootStore) => ({ user: state.user });
const mapActionsToProps = { logInUser };

// export default VisibilityFilters;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: That's totally it - I wasn't even thinking of the import. [Face-palm]